# Vscode API: when 'case' show contribution

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to set the context menu in a `TreeView` on a ftp extension that I am writing.
In the `package.json` I can add a `"when"` case in which I am trying to check if the `viewItem` is a directory or a file.

I have found this [link,](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts)
 which shows all the `"when"` cases. I am following [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/tree-view-sample/package.json)
example.

I am trying to accomplish something like this:

```json
"view/item/context": [
    {
        "command": "liveworkspace.checkout",
        "when": "view == live-workspace-remote && viewItem == file"
    }
]
```

I am pretty sure that I am doing it wrong, but am uncertain of the correct way.

Comment: Did you set `contextValue` to `file`? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/tree-view-sample/src/fileExplorer.ts#L292

Comment: Did you register your command in `commands` section in `package.json`?

Comment: @Alex I did register It,  and the option shows up if I remove the when, I think the link you shared may be what I need to do, But I followed the FTP guide which does not use the `contextValue`. I will look into it, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex Pointed me into the right direction in the comments the way I ended up doing this is as follows:

Inside my `TreeViewDataProvider` I added the following line

```
contextValue: element.isDirectory ? 'folder' : 'file'
```

To give perspective this was my `getTreeItem`

```
    public getTreeItem(element: FtpNode): vscode.TreeItem {
    console.log(element.resource.path);

    return {
        resourceUri: element.resource,
        collapsibleState: element.isDirectory ? vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.Collapsed : void 0,
        command: element.isDirectory ? void 0 : {
            command: 'live-workspace.openFtpResource',
            arguments: [element.resource],
            title: 'Open File'
        },
        contextValue: element.isDirectory ? 'folder' : 'file'  //Here I am!
    };
}
```

**`contextValue`** is an expected return for a treeItem, giving it additional information to be used in the `package.json`, now I can do my comparison as follows:

```
"view/item/context": [
   {
       "command": "liveworkspace.checkout",
       "when": "view == live-workspace-remote && viewItem == file" // or viewItem == folder
   }
]
```